# How to stick out a div on left and right

Tags: html, css

I have a super simple example with a wrapper div and another div inside this wrapper called header.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: #06c;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    logo
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible that the inner div called header sticks out of the wrapper on both sides with lets say 20px or even 100viewport wodth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the inner header to stick out 20px. You can do that with negative margins:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: #06c;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    logo
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want it to stretch through the whole viewport, you might have to position the element absolutely and use `left: 0; right: 0;`, however IMO it would be cleaner to move the div out of the container in that case.

Comment: Left:0 and right:0 wouldn‘t be that clean but what would be possible disadvanthes?

Comment: @STORM you'd have to position it absolutely and then make sure that the content following the header doesn't move below the header

Comment: Thanks! I have changed the header and added to it top:0; and added also to .content margin-top:50; Bow it looks very good but i would prefer also just havin some dxtra negative margin. That would be enough. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could give it a negative left/right margin:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
  background-color: #06c;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    logo
  </div>
</div>
```